# Django, set formset/object date manually

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I want to make a simple app for car mechanics but i have a problem which i cant figure out on my own since im a newbie. From start, i have list of services made to a car, and parts used, grouped by day in bootstrap accordion (like this https://ibb.co/8XWJx1S). In my edit view i grab all of services and parts from one certain day. In edit template i can add formsets dynamically (https://ibb.co/qBKL4Tk). The problem is when i add new service or part while editing, it saves with different date and then in list view its not grouped with services i want since its date is different. Is there a way to set this date manually to be the same as the other objects? Second option, not wanted but acceptable would be to update DATE.FIELD of other objects based on the new one, ive tried but failed

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Service', default=None)
    service_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Update parent model date_updated field whenever child object is added/edited"""
        self.car.save(update_fields=['date_updated'])
        super(Service, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class CarPart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_part = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Part')
    part_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    pdate_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Part: {self.car_part}  Price: {self.part_price}"
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ServiceAddView(CreateView):
    model = Service
    template_name = 'san_diego/service_add.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        car = Car.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))
        service_formset = ServiceFormSet(queryset=Service.objects.none(), prefix='service_formset')
        formset = CarPartFormSet(queryset=CarPart.objects.none(), prefix='carpart_formset')
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=service_formset, formset=formset, car=car))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        car = Car.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))
        service_formset = ServiceFormSet(self.request.POST, prefix='service_formset')
        formset = CarPartFormSet(self.request.POST, prefix='carpart_formset')
        if service_formset.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(service_formset, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(service_formset, formset, car)

    def form_valid(self, service_formset, formset):
        form = service_formset.save(commit=False)
        formset = formset.save(commit=False)
        for f in form:
            f.car = Car.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))
            f.user = self.request.user
            f.save()
        for f in formset:
            f.car = Car.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))
            f.user = self.request.user
            f.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, service_formset, formset, car):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=service_formset, formset=formset, car=car))

    def get_success_url(self):
        """If statement is adding funcionality to SAVE AND ADD ANOTHER button."""
        car = get_object_or_404(Car, uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'), user=self.request.user)
        if "another" in self.request.POST:
            return reverse_lazy('service_add', kwargs={'uuid': car.uuid})
        return reverse_lazy('service_history', kwargs={'uuid': car.uuid})

import datetime

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ServiceEditView(UpdateView):
    model = Service
    template_name = 'san_diego/service_add.html'

    def get_object(self):
        """Pass UUID"""
        return Car.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get("uuid"))

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object =self.get_object()
        service_formset = ServiceFormSet(queryset=Service.objects.filter(
            car=self.get_object(), user=self.request.user, date_added=self.kwargs.get('date')), prefix='service_formset')
        formset = CarPartFormSet(queryset=CarPart.objects.filter(
            car=self.get_object(), user=self.request.user, pdate_added=self.kwargs.get('date')), prefix='carpart_formset')
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=service_formset, formset=formset))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        service_formset = ServiceFormSet(self.request.POST, prefix='service_formset')
        formset = CarPartFormSet(self.request.POST, prefix='carpart_formset')
        if service_formset.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(service_formset, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(service_formset, formset)

    def form_valid(self, service_formset, formset):
        form = service_formset.save(commit=False)
        formset = formset.save(commit=False)
        for f in form:
            f.car = self.get_object()
            f.user = self.request.user
            f.save()
        for f in formset:
            f.car = self.get_object()
            f.user = self.request.user
            f.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, service_formset, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=service_formset, formset=formset))
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        car = get_object_or_404(Car, uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'), user=self.request.user)
        return reverse_lazy('service_history', kwargs={'uuid': car.uuid})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out if someone would have a problem with this in the future. My first approach to this was correct, which is adding these lines to UpdateView BEFORE CALLING `f.save()`

`f.date_added = self.kwargs.get('date')`

It wasnt working because of this in models `date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)`
Ive researched it and it seems auto_now_add is non editable.
So i changed it to `date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)`